# How to numerically solve a system of ODEs using 4th order Runge-Kutta method integrating backwards?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve a system of two 2nd order ODEs using the 4th order Runge-Kutta (RK4) method. The equations are of the form:
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=f(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}),$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=g(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}),$$
where the overdot means time-derivative, i.e., $\dot{x}=\dfrac{dx}{dt},$ for any variable $x$.

Now, we can rewrite the above equations in the following form:
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=R,$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\Theta,$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=f(r,\theta,R,\Theta),$$
$$\frac{d\Theta}{dt}=g(r,\theta,R,\Theta).$$

These 4 equations can be easily solved using the RK4 algorithm. Also, note that, none of the integrands depend explicitly on the variable $t$.

**Problem:**

**I need to solve these four 1st order ODEs and plot the $r-\theta$ trajectory *in the backward direction*. This means that the initial values of $(r,\theta)$ are provided for a large value of $r$ and then the integration is performed backwards towards the origin. But, I am having the problem regarding how to implement this in the RK4 algorithm. What changes needs to be done in the RK4 code written for the forward integration?**

I am attaching the RK4 code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// ***********************************************************************************************

// The integrand for dr/dt 

double integrand1(double R) 
{ 
    return R;
}

// The integrand for dtheta/dt 

double integrand2(double T) 
{ 
    return T;
}

// The integrand for dR/dt 

double integrand3(double r, double theta, double T)
{
    double rnot, a=0.8, l=2.68, r1=3.5, term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, integrand3;       
    rnot = pow(a,0.125);
    term1 = (r*T*T);
    term2 = (1/((r-rnot)*(r-rnot)));
    term3 = ((l*l)/(2*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)));
    term4 = ((3*(r-2)*l*l)/(2*r*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)));
    term5 = ((3*r1*a*l)/(r*r*r*r));
    integrand3 = term1 - term2 - term3 + term4 + term5;
    return integrand3;
}

// The integrand for dT/dt 

double integrand4(double r, double theta, double R, double T)
{
    double l=2.68, term1, term2, integrand4;                                               
    term1 = ((r-2)*l*l*cos(theta))/(r*r*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)*sin(theta));
    term2 = ((2*R*T)/r);
    integrand4 = term1 - term2;
    return integrand4;
}


// --------------- THE RUNGE-KUTTA ALGORITHM --------------------

double rk4(double t0, double r0, double theta0, double R0, double T0, double t, double h, double arr[])    
{ 
    int n = (int)(fabs((t-t0)/h)); 
    double k1,k2,k3,k4,l1,l2,l3,l4,m1,m2,m3,m4,n1,n2,n3,n4;

    double r = r0;
    double theta = theta0;
    double R = R0;
    double T = T0;

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        {
        k1 = h*integrand1(R);
        l1 = h*integrand2(T);
        m1 = h*integrand3(r, theta, T);
        n1 = h*integrand4(r, theta, R, T);

        k2 = h*integrand1(R + 0.5*m1);
        l2 = h*integrand2(T + 0.5*n1);
        m2 = h*integrand3(r + 0.5*k1, theta + 0.5*l1, T + 0.5*n1);
        n2 = h*integrand4(r + 0.5*k1, theta + 0.5*l1, R + 0.5*m1, T + 0.5*n1);
        
        k3 = h*integrand1(R + 0.5*m2);
        l3 = h*integrand2(T + 0.5*n2);
        m3 = h*integrand3(r + 0.5*k2, theta + 0.5*l2, T + 0.5*n2);
        n3 = h*integrand4(r + 0.5*k2, theta + 0.5*l2, R + 0.5*m2, T + 0.5*n2);

        k4 = h*integrand1(R + m3);
        l4 = h*integrand2(T + n3);
        m4 = h*integrand3(r + k3, theta + l3, T + n3);
        n4 = h*integrand4(r + k3, theta + l3, R + m3, T + n3);

        r = r + (1.0/6.0)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
        theta = theta + (1.0/6.0)*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4);
        R = R + (1.0/6.0)*(m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4);
        T = T + (1.0/6.0)*(n1 + 2*n2 + 2*n3 + n4);      

        arr[0] = r;     
        arr[1] = theta;
        arr[2] = R;
        arr[3] = T;

        t0 = t0 + h; 
    } return 0;
} 



// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ------------------
// The main function
//-------------------

int main() 
{ 
double t0=1000.0,r0=50.0,theta0=1.0467,R0=0.0,T0=0.0,t,r,theta,R,T,a,h=-0.001,x,z,arr[4],i;

FILE *fp1=NULL;
fp1=fopen("rthetaplot.txt","w");


// Integration

for(t=999.0;t>=0.0;t-=1.0)
{
rk4(t0,r0,theta0,R0,T0,t,h,arr);
r = arr[0];
theta = arr[1];
R = arr[2]; 
T = arr[3];
x = r*sin(theta);
z = r*cos(theta);
fprintf(fp1,"%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n", t,r,theta,R,T,x,z);
}


fclose(fp1);
}
```

**Can anyone please suggest what necessary changes are required so that the backward integration can be easily performed?**

EDIT: I have entered the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change nothing. Just stay with $(t_0,u_0)$ as the initial point where the initial condition is given, $t$ or $t_{end}$ the point where the integration has to end, and use a negative step size $h$ to move backwards in time if $t_{end}<t_0$.

Comment: Okay. This means that I need to take negative step size $h=-0.0001$ and the for-loop would run from $t=5000$ to $t=0$.

Comment: Yes. But check your step size, it seems to be rather small. If you have a Lipschitz constant for $f$ and $g$, then $ |h|=0.001/\sqrt{L}$ or around that should give optimal accuracy.

Comment: I had tried the way you suggested, but the code didn't run. The for-loop for $t$ runs but the values obtained from the RK4 method are all zero, i.e., when i tabulate the values, only the time coordinate is decremented and all other values are zero.

Comment: This is strange. The forward integration still works with changing values? I could understand if the values follow a spiral, depending on the initial values, if the functions $f,g$ for some reason return zero. But a jump to zero from non-zero initial values has to be some programming error in parts of the code you did  not publish here.

Comment: You should fill `arr` only after the end of the time loop. In the current version that you get the unchanged zero values of `arr` back means that the time loop inside RK4 is never entered. `int n = (int)(fabs(t-t0)/h);` can be negative, use `int n = (int)fabs((t-t0)/h);`. But that still does not guarantee that `n*h==t-t0`. One could compensate somewhat with `h=(t-t0)/n;` after computing `n`.

Comment: Your suggestion to include the $h$ inside the argument of 'fabs' was useful. Now the code is running but I am not getting the desired plot. So I have edited the question and entered the entire code.

Comment: You have a singularity at $r=r_{not}$ and $r=0$. From the first you get problems with RK4 stability as soon as $h>0.5·(r-r_{not})$, from the second as soon as $h>0.5·r^{5/2}$. In total RK4 should start to diverge and be chaotic at $r\sim\max(10^{-3}+2·10^{-4}, 10^{-1-3/5})$, so roughly at $r\sim 10^{-2}$. Before that the numerical solution should at least be plausible, with some slight deterioration in accuracy. Do you observe this pattern?

Comment: Yes, I could understand your analysis. The trajectories are actually that of a particle moving around a rotating black hole and would have oscillatory pattern. The link to the paper that I am trying to reproduce is https://zero.sci-hub.se/279/1d21fa1a6053286cb9500609861c8d9e/lu1995.pdf?download=true and I have written the code to reproduce the figure 1 of the paper. The horizon of the black hole is at $r=1.6$ so that the only relevant region is $r>1.6$. I am having trouble to obtain the oscillatory motion.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was calculating, $r_0=a^{0.125}\approx 1$, so the first singularity is at about $r=1$, and to pass over this singularity one should use a power series approximation. Alternatively, replace $1/(r-r_0)^2$ with $1/(\epsilon^2+(r-r_0)^2)$, but if $\epsilon$ is small, the step size has to be equally small, so use a variable-step method or modification of RK4 (step doubling, Richardson extrapolation), or switch the integration over to the gsl or boost::odeint methods with step size control.

Comment: As you had suggested earlier, I had used a negative step size and the for-loop running from a large $t$ to $t=0$. Now I have figured out the actual problem: The particle trajectory would start from a large $r$ and move inward and since I am using a negative step size,  the radial derivative $\dot{r}=R$ should always be positive. The moment $R$ becomes negative, the particle starts to move outside, and this is what I need to restrict. So I need to impose a condition that $R$ always remain positive. Could you please suggest how to include that condition in my code?

Comment: I think you need to implement the idea of "marginally bound orbit". This feels like it should be a boundary value problem, and moreover one that is very sensitive to the initial data at the outer boundary point. You would need a multiple-shooting approach or, for a single-shooting approach, a regularizing modification of the right sides outside the domain of the expected solution. Setting $T=R=0$ at the outer boundary appears to be insufficient.

Comment: Yes, for a marginally bound orbit, the constraint that the total energy $E=1$ could be used to find a set of initial values for $R$ and $T$. I had already tried this case but I couldn't implement the condition that the radial derivative $R$ remains always positive. At a certain $r$, the variable $R$  changes sign and the trajectory starts to move outwards instead of moving inwards.

Comment: This however is not a discussion about errors in the model, but selecting trajectories with specific physical interpretation. So it would be better asked in astronomy.SE (or space.SE?) or physics.SE. I would not post the code there, just a link to this page, but give the system in mathematical formulas.